# How to check multiple values in an if statement PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

Have some data posted to me :

```
test.com?firstname='John'&surname='Wick'&email='jwick@test.com'
```

What I want to do is check the above data with what I have in my DB, and if any of the data is the same then echo out a response and if its not the same then echo out a different response. It needs to check all 3 fields, even if 2 Don't match and one does.

Lets assume the value's from my DB request are:

```
$Email = 'jwick@test.com';
$FirstName = 'John';
$Surname = 'Wick';
```

This is what I have tried :

```
if(
        $Email == $_GET['email'] &&
        $FirstName == $_GET['firstname'] &&
        $Surname == $_GET['surname']

    ){}
```

What happens is it only compares the `$Email` and ignores the rest, what is the best way to do this. Basically what i am trying to do is that is create a simple dedupe

Comment: I think you need to check with `OR` condition rather than `AND`, if I understood your requirement correctly.

Comment: *if any of the data is the same*: It sounds like you need `||` instead of `&&`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of AND (&&) clause use the OR (||) clause:

```
if(     $Email == $_GET['email'] ||
    $FirstName == $_GET['firstname'] ||
    $Surname == $_GET['surname']

){ //do somthing}
```

It will check if any one condition is true and matched with the posted data then it will execute the if condition.

### *Clarification:*

**AND(&&)** condition always check all the condition should be true and matched.

**OR(||)** condition is used to check any of the given condition should be true. It may one condition or more than one condition can be fullfill.